# Creating delay on outputstream

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am dealing with a special task, where i need to create a delay on TCP outputstream. This is due to restriction on the receiver device.

The other problem i might be facing is overflow in the output buffer, since i might be writing to it way too fast compared to the reduced transmission speed.

How would one deal with this kind of problem?

Comment: You should be aware that TCP doesn't directly support what you're trying to do. You can delay passing your data into the kernel, and obviously the kernel can't send it before you've passed it, but it might also have buffered the previous data and so the new data and the previous data may go out on the line at the same time. And every device along the route may do something similar. Your data may even arrive at the destination device out of order (although TCP guarantees that the receiving *application* will see it in order).

Comment: @KenThomases, synchronizity should not be a problem since i pass one string at a time doing a particular function. The way the program is builded up right now its not a problem. But its a challenge finding the correct way to handle this. Whether i should use a timed queue or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not exactly sure whether you need a solution for MacOSX or iOS but as you have only tagged Objective -C try looking into this documentation link

[performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsobject_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

This method will let you perform you code after a delay! there are other methods for performing on main thread or else in background.

Comment: Cool, the link is pointing to iOS now! hope this is what you are looking for :)